# File does not appear in Google Drive - Google docs created with Python

Tags: python, google-docs, google-docs-api

Code shown hereafter runs fine. I see the file being created in my Jupiter notebook so the script seems to work. Only problem is, the file does not appear in my Drive.

```py
creds_1 = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds_1.json", scope)
service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds_1)
title = 'My Document'
body = {
  "body": {},
  "title": "My document2"
}
doc = service.documents().create(body=body).execute()
print('Created document with title: {0}'.format(doc.get('title')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the Service Account has it's own Drive, so you are not uploading it to your personal Drive. The Service Account is separate from your user.

An option would be to create a folder in your Drive, share it with the Service Account and make the code upload the files there.

Another method, if you are a [G Suite User](https://gsuite.google.com/), would be configuring the Service Account to impersonate your user with [Domain Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) and upload the files directly to your Drive.

Comment: Thank you. I more or less understand what I need to do. I am a G Suite User but still struggling with the various steps involved in setting up Domain Wide Delegation so did not have a chance to succeed yet. Will keep you posted. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. You can visit this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58860627/google-calendar-api-daily-limit-for-unauthenticated-use-exceeded-continued-use/58873195#58873195) with the steps to perform Domain Wide Delegation. Also, you might want to accept my answer is it was helpful to you :)